# Event not work in dynamically adding button to html

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've added some html elements including a button to page but when click this button the event does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  loginpannel.InnerHtml = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse'><li><a  class='active'><i class='fa fa-lock'>welcome ," + Session["username"] + " </i> </a></li><li class='dropdown'><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-angle-down'>  Account</i></a> <ul role='menu' class='sub-menu'><li><button OnClick='btnlogin1_Click'  runat='server'  CssClass='btnLogin' id='btnlogin1'>logout</button></li></ul></li><li><a href=''><i class='fa fa-star'></i> Wishlist</a></li><li><a href='checkout.aspx'><i class='fa fa-crosshairs'></i> Checkout</a></li><li><a href='cart.aspx'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i> Cart</a></li></ul>";
}

protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
  {
    user loginuser = new user();
    loginuser = db.users.Where(x => x.username == loginName.Value && x.password ==loginpassword.Value  &&x.approved==true).Select(x => x).First();

    Session["username"] = loginuser.username;

    loginpannel.InnerHtml = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse'><li><a  class='active'><i class='fa fa-lock'>welcome ," + Session["username"] + " </i> </a></li><li class='dropdown'><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-angle-down'>  Account</i></a> <ul role='menu' class='sub-menu'><li><button OnClick='btnlogin1_Click'  runat='server'  CssClass='btnLogin' id='btnlogin1'>logout</button></li></ul></li><li><a href=''><i class='fa fa-star'></i> Wishlist</a></li><li><a href='checkout.aspx'><i class='fa fa-crosshairs'></i> Checkout</a></li><li><a href='cart.aspx'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i> Cart</a></li></ul>";
  }
}

protected void btnlogin1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  Session["username"] = null;
  Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't load ASP.NET controls in the Page_Load event, they won't be recognized as ASP.NET controls in your web page and thus there will be no event handler connected. The controls must be in your ASPX page; not in the code-behind.

Besides; I'd use `<asp:Button>` instead of `<button>`

Comment: i know that it should be in html file of design but i have a page that when user log in i change the menu and add some elements including a li for log out. so i do this way. do u have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should used asp:button control along with hidden li portion. And than whenever you want used that make it visible. i hope this is useful to you.